# Why is my Tkinter Scrollbar on top of the region it's supposed to scroll?

Tags: python, tkinter

My problem, in a nutshell, is that in a GUI I'm writing I've got scrollbars overlapping on top of the right-hand edge of the frame instead of adjacent to it as intended.  What am I doing wrong here?  A bit of code reproducing the problem:

```
root=Tk()
root.title('Window Test')
root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

overall=Frame(root)
overall.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+E+S+W)
overall.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

outercanvas=Canvas(overall)
outercanvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
outerSframe=LabelFrame(outercanvas,text='Outer')
outerSB=Scrollbar(overall,command=outercanvas.yview)
outercanvas.config(yscrollcommand=outerSB.set)
outerSframe.bind('<Configure>',lambda e: outercanvas.configure(scrollregion=outercanvas.bbox('all')))
outercanvas.create_window((0,0),window=outerSframe,anchor=NW)
outerSB.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+E+S)

innercanvas=Canvas(outerSframe)
innercanvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
innerSframe=LabelFrame(innercanvas,text='Inner')
innercanvas.create_window((0,0),window=innerSframe,anchor=NW)
Label(innerSframe,text='123456789012345678901234567890').pack()
```

Comment: Should `innerSframe` be child of `innercanvas`, not `outercanvas`?.

Comment: Yes it should, correcting that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your code does not specify the width of `outercanvas`.  You should set its width based on the width of `outerSframe` inside callback binded to `<Configure>` event:

```
def on_frame_resize(event):
    bbox = outercanvas.bbox('all')
    outercanvas.config(scrollregion=bbox, width=bbox[2]) # update width as well

root=Tk()
root.title('Window Test')
root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

overall=Frame(root)
overall.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+E+S+W)
overall.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

outercanvas=Canvas(overall)
outercanvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
outerSframe=LabelFrame(outercanvas,text='Outer')
outerSB=Scrollbar(overall,command=outercanvas.yview)
outercanvas.config(yscrollcommand=outerSB.set)
outerSframe.bind('<Configure>', on_frame_resize) # changed to a function instead of lambda
outercanvas.create_window((0,0),window=outerSframe,anchor=NW)
outerSB.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+E+S)

innercanvas=Canvas(outerSframe)
innercanvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
innerSframe=LabelFrame(innercanvas,text='Inner')
innercanvas.create_window((0,0),window=innerSframe,anchor=NW)
Label(innerSframe,text='123456789012345678901234567890').pack()

root.mainloop()
```